# Question about projections on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $P_i$ be projections from a Hilbert space $\cal{H}$ to its closed subspace $\cal{H}_i$, $i=1,2,\cdots,n$, such that  $\sum^n_{i=1} P_i$ is also a projection. And let $P$ be a projection from $\cal{H}$ to $[\bigcup \cal{H}_i]$ the closed subspace spaned by $\bigcup \cal{H}_i$.

Is $\sum P_i$ justly $P$?

When $n=2$, it is true and easy to prove. But when $n>2$, there is some difficult for me to prove that $\sum^n_{i=1} P_i=P$.

Thanks a lot to anyone who can give me a hint.

Comment: What does this sentence mean "If $\sum_{i=1}^n\mathcal{H}_i$ is also a projection"? Do you mean to say that all subspaces are pairwise orthogonal?

Comment: I am sorry, it is an error. I have crrected. I do not mean all projection are pairwise orthogonal. May be it is right, but need to  prove.

Comment: are you assuming that $P_i^*=P_i$, i.e. $P_i$ are orthogonal projections?

Comment: Yes. all of the projections are orthogonal projections.

Comment: And you need to prove that $P$ is orthogonal projection too. Right?

Comment: No, $P$, $P_i$ and $\sum P_i$ are orthogonal projection. I want to prove that $\sum P_i=P$ if it is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** the following statement solves your problem:

**Statement:** If $P_1,\dots,P_n\in\mathcal H$ are orthogonal projections such that $\sum_{i=1}^n P_i$ is again an orthogonal projection, then $P_i$ are pairwise orthogonal, i.e. $P_iP_j=0,\ i\neq j.$

**Edit.**

Proof. If $Q,R$ are projections such that $Q\geq R$ then $Q\supseteq R.$ Indeed, let $x\in Ran R.$ Then $||Qx||^2=\langle Qx,x\rangle\geq \langle Rx,x\rangle=||x||^2,$ hence $x\in Ran Q.$ In particular, $Q-R$ is also a projection and $Q-R\perp R.$

Since $\sum_{i=1}^nP_i\geq P_n$ are projections, $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}P_i$ is a projection and $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}P_i\perp P_n.$ Induction over $n$ completes the proof. $\Box$

Comment: Thank you! It is a nice hint. But how to yield $P_i$ are pairwise orthogonal by these two equation. $\cal{H}$ is a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Zhonghua Wang: I have deleted those equations.